# How do I create a communal share with Samba?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to set up a "communal" share on a samba server. I want it to have these properties:

- Anyone that is part of group X can read/write anything on the share, including files created by other people.
- Anyone else can read files but not write them.

After some thought, I think the way to achieve this is to force everything created on the share to be owned by group X and have 775/664 permissions. Is this a good method, and if so, how do I configure Samba to do this?

Edited to add:

After reading up on this, I've setgid on the top-level directory and set these options in the share definition:

```
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
create directory mask = 2775
force directory mode = 2775
```

This appears to do what I want for files; they get created with the right permissions and the right group owner. However, any directories I make get created with drwxrwsrwx permissions (i.e. everything permitted to everyone), and I can't figure out why.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here. What have you tried? You usually have to config create masks in your smb.conf (http://www.bodenzord.com/archives/53). As for the groups (http://askubuntu.com/questions/335055/how-to-force-group-ownership-on-samba-share)

Comment: you nee to use write list and read list in samba, man smb.conf